# when i fetch data from api using for loop i am getting error in react native

Tags: react-native

```
async makeRemoteRequestNotification() {
var backapi = api.Backend_API();
let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userid");
fetch(backapi + "event/notification/" + userId, {
  method: "GET",
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
   for(let i in data){
       fetch(backapi+"event/eventname/"+data[i].event_id,{
           method:'GET',
       }).then((response)=>response.json())
         .then((data)=>{
             this.state.data.push(data)
             console.log("notification event",this.state.data);
         })
       console.log("created_by",data[i].created_by);
    fetch(backapi+"user/getUserById"+data[i].created_by,{
        method:'GET'
    }).then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log("username",data);
    })     
   }
  //  this.state.data=data;
    console.log("clint",this.state.data);
  })
};
```

getting error as

> Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
>   in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

You should check the status of you response before `.then((response) => response.json())`

For example you can do:

```
.then((response) => {
  if (response.status == 200) {
    //Deal with your response and do whatever you want
  }
  else {
   //do somthing with your error status
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related to react native. You are getting error when trying to parse an invalid json response (or not json at all). Use debug tools to catch the incorrect server response and use the `catch` block in promise chain to process such situations.